# Is an open-source software contributor a valid work reference?

Tags: united-states, applications, references

I am applying on multiple new careers, and I came across a question on one of them titled "Work References":

> Name:
>   Phone:
>   Worked Together At:

Now these are limited for me (unless I use multiple persons from the same employer) so naturally I filled in what I could, and continued on. (Possibly going to hurt in the long run, but it's what I have at my disposal.)

My question is: as a contributor to an open-source project(s), can I use **one** other contributor / maintainer as a work reference? Is that an appropriate response to this particular hiring question? I am speaking of *non*-superiors in regards to the context of the hiring question asked. I.e. coworkers, etc.

More context: the project I'm interested in using affects multiple users (at least more than one) and has the possibility of becoming more popular in the future. It also demonstrates knowledge of and experience with vital technologies to the particular field I am applying for, and, as I have been directly responsible for closing multiple issues on the GitHub repository, demonstrates that I have an intimate relationship with the project (and other users).

We also (regularly) communicate through a Stack Exchange chat room which we use for white-boarding, brainstorming and discussion of the task at hand, *besides* the GitHub issues/commits. However: *I have never had face-to-face or direct verbal communication with them.* We have also **never** done pair-programming. We *have* worked on the same portion of code at the same time and merged each of our work together through the chat room, commits, issues and pull requests.

The problem is, if this is acceptable, how do I fill out the form (considering I am in the United States, and some of the possibilities may be in other countries)?

> **Name:** An Awesome Contributor
>   **Phone:** xxx-xxx-xxxx
>   **Worked Together At:** Awesome Open Source Project X

I only intend to include **one** Open-Source Software Contributor in my work-references, until I build a larger list of them. I can get two others very easily via previous employment, but the third would **have** to come from one of the two same employers. (This would mean that I would have two references from company Y, and one from company Z.)

Comment: Have you ever talked to or worked directly with your fellow contributors? Or is all communication done through github comments & issues?

Comment: @Erik We use an SE site chatroom for "white boarding" ideas, brainstorming and such, so yes-*ish*. (I've never had verbal/visual contact with them, but we chat daily.)

Comment: Okay, that will help. No genuine pair programming then, I guess?

Comment: @Erik We've never been working within the same room, but *we have* worked on similar (and the same) features at the same time on at least one occasion, where each person committed their share and then we combined them. (This is also very public record.)

Comment: Pair programming isn't about working on the same features, but about really working on the same thing at the same time. You don't have to be in the same time, but you need to be using a remote-working tool. It gives you a lot of insight in how your partner works and thinks that you won't get from seeing their code.

Comment: @Erik Ah, in that case, then *no*, we have never done that. We have only worked on the same aspects of the project at the same time, but never remotely-viewed the other person's work.

Comment: Some related advice: **never provide references before you've had at least one interview**. Normal companies won't care as they typically only do to get administrative stuff out of the way early. Bad companies will call references too early or abuse the information, as will fake companies. When you provide references you should be giving them a heads-up which is annoying to do too early in an application. In a similar vein: scrap "references available on request" from your application materials, that's assumed.

Comment: @Lilienthal The problem with that, is that in this case, the form fields are *required* for all three work references.

Comment: Why on earth would you think it was bad to provide two references from the same job? NOthing against open source if you have nothing else, but apparently you do, so why not use them?

Comment: You're applying for multiple _careers_?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Considering I have experience in at least three major career paths in the IT scope, yes.

Comment: @EBrown Knew I forget something: required fields in submission forms are the only place where you still write "available on request" or a bunch of slashes (/). Sadly such form applications are common these days but any company that doesn't realise that references shouldn't be asked that early or who don't approve of the standard practice for candidates to leave those fields empty is not a company I'd want to work for.

Comment: @EBrown: But you don't "apply to careers"

Comment: I think you'll find any company that doesn't recognize your contributions to an open source project, isn't going to be a good fit for you anyway.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can add these people. In fact, you can add anyone you like as a reference, doesn't even need to be in the same field. I've been a reference for a friend who wanted an IT-job, even though we've only worked together as volunteers on something completely unrelated.

The key points to keep in mind when selecting a reference are:

- (does this person want to be my reference, obviously)
- does this person know me well enough to answer questions about *how* I work
- can this person give insights into why I'd be a valuable addition to the company
- does this person know anything about my technical skills and suitability for the tasks I'll be hired for
- Will this person not be obviously biased (this is why you don't add your partner or parent, even if you've worked with them)

Ideally, you'll pick people who match all of these: previous colleagues or managers from the same sector are the best matches for that reason. (Additionally, some people weigh paid work more highly than non-paid work, so that also factors into why previous colleagues are seen as best)

But sometimes you can't fill the list with those, because you're new to the field, or just starting your career, or whatever. In that case, you can add some people that miss one of the points (your online collaborators miss out on point 2, while with my volunteer friend I missed out on point 4) as long as you make sure that you have at least one reference on each point. (It'll look bad if none of your references have ever worked with you, or none of them know your technical skills.)

Just make sure you disclose this information when you give your references. It looks really bad if they ask this guy "so, what it's like working with him" and they *then* find out he's never met you. But if they know this is going to be a technical-skills interview, they can ask different questions and still learn a bit more about you.

Comment: I think this makes the most sense - I can get by having them fall short on point 2 considering the *two* other references would meet that criteria. I'll just make sure to put this person *last* on the list, to help alleviate the chances of them being contacted (should they agree to it, that is).

Comment: You've missed the *most* important point when selecting a reference: "Does this person like me?" (or at the very least "... actively dislike me?"

Comment: @MartinBonner Heh... yeah I assumed that would be a given.

Answer (score 7):

Sure you can, it's not worth as much as 'real' work, but it's a lot better than nothing. Try and get some of the skillset required to do your part included, because that is the important bit.

Comment: Could you elaborate on *why*? I feel that an Open-Source project has the possibility to be just as valuable, in the case that the project touches many users, and requires approval / interaction of other users to work appropriately. It's also a very public timeline - potential employers could easily determine how "valuable" my contributions were via the tracking of the project.

Comment: Because these public projects can be harder to validate than 'real work'. It's easy enough to make a fake projects and get friends to say you were a great contributor, making an enterprise just for references tends to be a little hard, hence a little more valuable.

Comment: @Draken I guess the problem that I have with that ideology is in two parts: first, this particular open-source project is very public and very easy to validate the legitimacy of, and uses a great deal many features of specific language(s) that I work regularly with; second, it wouldn't be *terribly* hard to spoof "legitimate" employment (and recommendations) from a "real" (fake) company: "sorry, but I cannot disclose any information regarding app x, as it is an internal app which is unavailable even for discussion to person not members of this company."

Comment: As an example, try spoofing employment at a big company like IBM. Although you provide a reference as a friend who pretends to work there, it's easy enough to find other contact details elsewhere and confirm this employment was true. An open source project, could be difficult to prove which user was who without some kind of public profile detailing full names. I could say I was a contributor to project X for many years and have a friend back me up, that can be harder to verify. Just because a project is public, doesn't mean the contributors are easily contactable.

Comment: However, there are always exceptions to the rule, I'm just trying to provide a general example as to why "real work" could be considered more reputable. It's not always the case, however it often is

Comment: @Draken I can get by that, I was simply curious on *why* it might be frowned upon. In my case, I have a limited subset of them to choose from. (When most of your employment history is between two jobs, it's hard to come up with a third reference *without* pulling from the same pool, especially when you only worked with 2 people at each job, and at one of them all your co-workers were supervisors due to it being similar to an internship.)

Comment: I wouldn't say frowned upon, just not as highly regarded. I would definitely use it in your CV because it sounds like fantastic work. You may get an odd look from the older generation, but I shouldn't worry too much about that.

Comment: @EBrown Consider the kind of position the hiring manager is looking to fill -- probably you'd be working on site with a team. Your open source project experience may well demonstrate your technical ability, but not do as much for your ability to work with several people on a team.

Comment: @Draken If you claim to have contributed to project X, I'd expect your reference to be `friend@foundation.x.org`, which is as hard to spoof as `friend@ibm.com`

Comment: @EBrown: I think Kilisi is saying that _he_ would value this open source contribution less, and you can't argue with that. If a potential employer agrees with him, don't be surprised.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev However spoofing a friend that you have who also works at IBM is a lot harder. Companies are more difficult as people can belong to a social click that interact with each other. You have a HR department to contact, etc. Meanwhile, a contributed project could just be a repository on GitHub. These are two very different things when it comes to references.

Comment: It's less value for several reasons, it's harder to prove, and it's volunteer, which means you worked on your own time without supervisory authority over you and a host of other reasons which don't advertise you as a good 'EMPLOYEE' which is what employers are after. Tech skills are not everything, plenty of solid employees have proven tech skills, proven social skills, proven work ethic etc,. It's still another asset you can use though just of lesser worth than an actual solid job history.

Comment: I find it rather sad that some people consider OSS contributions as not "real" work. I own an OSS project that covers a ***MUCH*** wider area of knowledge than every single "real-work" app I've ever worked on (which, honestly, are more often than not nothing more than more or less sophisticated CRUD apps). Not to mention, any contributor's specific contributions are all public on GitHub - IMO it's much easier to spoof work on some in-house proprietary app project that nobody will ever see, than on some public OSS project where all your individual commits can be consulted by anyone.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - I think technical knowledge and even the ability to show some horse-power by doing a certain amount of work, can be demonstrated in an open source project. What you can't do, and unfortunately many jobs require, is also a willingness to show up on time, act appropriately, attend meetings, respond to email, provide documentation even when you think it is worthless, track your time, and put up with your boss's crap. As a work reference, I could vouch for someone being able to do all the aspects of a job and not just the programming.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can and should list interesting open source projects you have worked on, and if you have contributed significantly, and really worked as part of the team, then feel free to list them as references.

Opensource projects on a resume have more value to me then closed source projects listed. I can look at the code, and complexity of the team and see that you can write code, and that you can handle tasks related to the politics of submitting a commit on a large project.

Often times, I ask for, and am asked for, GitHub profiles. It's a good way to get a glimpse of how you work. I can do a quick code review, see your coding style, and see how well you conform to the groups coding style.  There are of course caveats, but it's far better then nothing, or a take home "mini-project", or "skills tests".

As for format list it like you would anything else. For the reference, how you have it in your question is totally fine. Just keep in mind that people still call references, and you don't want your reference to say "Who?" so you better give them a heads up (as you should with all your references).

Comment: I *have* listed multiple open-source projects on my Resume, and my GitHub itself. This project  is not (yet) one of them, but it will probably make it on there to help solidify my participation with it should I proceed this route.